# Clustering using Self organizing map model (Package kohenon) in R

Tags: r

I want to use kohenon SOM model from kohenon package in R to cluster the data. My data is in cure.csv file with 4000 lines having two columns as shown below. All values are real numbers.

```
X     Y
0.99 0.56  //line 1
0.32 -0.23  //line 2
```

and the below code executes.

```
    curedf <- read.csv('cure.csv',header=F)


data_train_matrix <- as.matrix(scale(curedf))


som_grid <- somgrid(xdim = 20, ydim=20, topo="hexagonal")

som_model <- som(data_train_matrix, 
        grid=som_grid)
```

Now i want to save the clustering output but how to do it.

```
X      Y    Cluster
0.99 0.56   1       //line 1
0.32 -0.23  2       //line 2
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to save the `data.frame` to a file or you want to save the `model`?

Comment: i want to use the som_model to assign the cluster id to each point in the data matrix data_train_matrix.

Comment: You can use `cbind()` to add the cluster id as another column corresponding to each data point in the matrix.

Comment: but how to obtain cluster id